# React Calling Parent's Method Nothing Happens

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Probably a simple question and have so many people answered here but in this scenario, I cannot figure out why it doesn't work ...

In the parent I have

```
     updateAccountNumber = value => {
        console.log(value);
      };

<Child updateAccountNumber={this.updateAccountNumber} />
```

In the child I have

```
<ListItem
          button
          key={relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account}
          onClick={() =>
            this.props.updateAccountNumber(
              relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account
            )
          }
```

Even if I do parent like this, still no help..

```
 <Child updateAccountNumber={() => this.updateAccountNumber()} />
```

if I have the below child item, then when I click on the menu that runs the child items, the component calls itself as many items as there are...

```
 onClick={this.props.updateAccountNumber(
        relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account
      )}
```

It won't even run the below code, simple code, I can't see why it wouldn't kick of the handleClick event...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

const handleClick = () => {
  debugger;
  alert("sda");
  console.log("bbb");
};

export default class RelatedSubAccounts extends Component {
  Links = () => {
    if (this.props.RelatedSubAccounts) {
      let RelatedSubArray = this.props.RelatedSubAccounts;
      let source = RelatedSubArray.map(relatedSub => (
        <ListItem
          button
          onClick={handleClick}
          key={relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account}
          className={
            relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account !== this.props.OfficeAccount
              ? ""
              : "CurrentRelatedSub"
          }
        >
          <ListItemText primary={relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account} />
        </ListItem>
      ));

      return (
        <div id="RelatedSubLinks">
          <List>{source}</List>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  render() {
    return this.Links();
  }
}
```

Please ask if any other related code is missing, and I can share.

Comment: Could you create a sandbox to play with the code and got more insights?

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez So this one works just fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-bpti1 .... I made it so simple so I can see where's the error. But then this code on my app still not working.. I can't see any reason why not?? all it does is run the handleClick in same document, it won't run it...

Comment: Can you show how you are using RelatedSubAccounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be strangest solution but might give you a lesson or two.. I found the cause of the issue here.

So I have a menu like this
[image]

When you click on that arrow to open up the menu, it becomes active and when you click away onBlur kicks in and that menu goes away.. (menu created used react-select Creatable)

```
  DropdownIndicator = props => {
    return (
      <div
        onBlur={() => {
          this.setState({ Focused: false, RelatedSub: false });
        }}
```

so I had to update it to below:

```
onBlur={() => {
      this.setState({ Focused: false });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ RelatedSub: false });
      }, 100);
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get an example that works with the code you shared by using `RelatedSubAccounts` like this:

```
<RelatedSubAccounts RelatedSubAccounts={[{ office: 1, account: 2 }]} />
```

[Code Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o9mx3)

I see a few things that stand out as potentially confusing. I will point them out in code below with comments:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

const handleClick = () => {
  debugger;
  alert("RelatedSubAccounts clicked");
  console.log("bbb");
};

export default class RelatedSubAccounts extends Component {
  // Capitalization like this in react normally indicates a component
  Links = () => {
    /*
      Having a prop that is the same name as the component and capitalized is confusing
      In general, props aren't capitalized like the component unless you are passing a component as a prop    
    */
    if (this.props.RelatedSubAccounts) {
      // Again, capitalization on RelatedSubArray hints that this is a component when it really isn't
      let RelatedSubArray = this.props.RelatedSubAccounts;
      let source = RelatedSubArray.map(relatedSub => (
        <ListItem
          button
          onClick={handleClick}
          key={relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account}
          className={
            relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account !== this.props.OfficeAccount
              ? ""
              : "CurrentRelatedSub"
          }
        >
          <ListItemText primary={relatedSub.office + relatedSub.account} />
        </ListItem>
      ));

      return (
        <div id="RelatedSubLinks">
          <List>{source}</List>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  render() {
    return this.Links();
  }
}
```

Comment: @B Rob, thank you... So why do you think mine doesn't work? It's got `onClick={handleClick}` and `const handleClick = () => {
  debugger;
  alert("RelatedSubAccounts clicked");
  console.log("bbb");
};` still not working...

Comment: Thank you for your example, it works great.When I click on mine on the listitem nothing happens...

Comment: So Strange, I literally pasted your whole file that works into my project, when you click on the item nothing happens...

Comment: even if I do `<ListItem
          button
          onClick={() => console.log("asd")}` nothing happens ..

Comment: @B Rob, thank you much, I figured it out eventually.